# Substring contains extra integers

Tags: android

I have a problem with substring

When i extract a character from a string it contains some extra integer with the result...

Can anyone help me  why this happening?

here is my code

```
    mySrtring ="12456+"  Char temp1 = myString.charAt(myString.length()-1);
```

it produce temp1='+' 443

Comment: Care to elaborate? Because a `Char` isn't a substring, it's a **single** (Unicode) character. So how do you determine that it contains an extra int?

Comment: The character '+' equals to decimal 43 in ASCII code.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

I assume you're saying this "43" in the debugger. It is correct. All magics inside the computer are nothing more than numbers. Those great minds once assigned certain numbers to represent certain characters, such as 65 for 'A' and 97 for 'a'. And 43 stands for '+', that's all. This kind of number-to-character mapping is called [ASCII (American Standard Code for Information Interchange)](http://www.asciitable.com/). And the modern IDE displays those numbers behind the character only for debugging convenience.

So, '+' is 43 (in decimal), and 43 (in decimal) can be '+' when you treat it as a character.

Furthermore, you can do something like `temp1 + 2` in C language and then it will give you 45, which is '-' in ASCII.

Comment: Thanks #Nandin Bao and dhke